How does Bergomi fit Heston model into Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman (HJB) stochastic control framework?
In Bergomi's paper "Smile Dynamics", he states as below:

I can understand his idea of minimising the variance of $P\&L$, i.e. $v_\Delta$, but just don't see how he fits the minimising problem into Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman (HJB) formulism.
To my understanding, in HJB framework, we need a gain function defined in form of
$$ J(t,x,\alpha) = \mathbb{E}\left[\int_t^T f(s,X_s^{t,x},\alpha_s)ds + g(X_T^{t,x})\right] $$ and
$$v(t,x)=\sup\limits_{\alpha} J(t,x,\alpha)$$, then we have HJB equation
$$ \frac{\partial v}{\partial t} = - \sup\limits_{\alpha}[\mathcal{L}^\alpha v(t,x) + f(t,x,\alpha)]$$
Now back to Bergomi's paper, since $v_\Delta$ is variance of $P\&L$, so it should be
$$ v_\Delta = \textrm{Var}[P\&L] = \mathbb{E}[(P\&L)^2] - \mathbb{E}[P\&L]^2 = \mathbb{E}[(P\&L)^2] - m_\Delta^2 $$. For the term $\mathbb{E}[(P\&L)^2]$, inevitably it will leads to exception of
$$ \left( \int_t^T e^{-r(\tau-t)}\Delta(\tau, S_\tau,\dots)(dS_\tau-(r-q)d\tau) \right)^2 $$
Then I get stuck on how to proceed to simplify this to fit the HJB formulism.
Could anyone kindly shed some light or provide some related material please? I also googled a lot but all I can found is optimise with HJB with self-defined utility function, there is no paper/article on how to optimise against variance of hedged $P\&L$.
Thanks a lot！
